# returned book lending is not working in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have been created student library page in aspx and c#.

I added two buttons, one for book lending on submit click and another one is return button book returning.

For example:

I enter student id and book id and click submit means, it showed the staus as 'pending'.

or

If i enter same student id and book id for returning book, it showed the status as 'returned'.

The above process works fine.

But again if enter same student id and book id for book lending menas, it doesn't work.

May i know,?

I'm new to .net., can anyone guide me?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

source code:

book lending:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_lendingstatus", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", txtstudentid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid", txtbookid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Calendar1.TodaysDate.Date.ToString());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@returndate", Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString());
                SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("@output", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                com.Parameters.Add(retval);
                txtstudentid.Text = string.Empty;
                txtbookid.Text = string.Empty;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string Output = retval.Value.ToString();
                output.Text = Output;

        }
```

return:

```
protected void btnrtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_bookreturn", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", txtstudentid.Text.Trim());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid", txtbookid.Text.Trim());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@returnstatus", txtbookid.Text.Trim());
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

page-load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
                {
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_selectlendingstatus", con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                  
                    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(ds);
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }
```

sp_selectlendingstatus:(page_load for showing status)

```
select *, (CASE WHEN book_lending.bookid IS NULL THEN 'Available' ELSE 'Not 
Available' END) as status from studentlibrary left outer join book_lending 
ON book_lending.bookid=studentlibrary.Book_id and 
book_lending.returnstatus='pending'
```

sp_lendingstatus for book lending:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_lendingstatus
(
@studentid int,
@output varchar(50) output,
@bookid int,
@date varchar(50),
@returndate varchar(50)
)
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student WHERE ID=@studentid)
BEGIN
SET @output = 'student id does not exist'
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studentlibrary WHERE Book_id=@bookid) 
begin
SET @output = 'Book id does not exist'
END
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM book_lending inner join studentlibrary ON studentlibrary.Book_id=book_lending.bookid where Book_id=@bookid)
begin
SET @output = 'Book id not available'
return
End
ELSE
BEGIN
Insert into book_lending (studentid,bookid,date,returndate) values (@studentid,@bookid,@date,@returndate) 
END
```

book_return:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_bookreturn
(
@returnstatus varchar(50),
@bookid int,
@studentid int
)
AS
begin
update book_lending set returnstatus='Returned' where bookid=@bookid and studentid=@studentid
End
```

Note: I set foreign key for bookid and studentid.

Comment: Doesn't work how?  Simply saying doesn't work is like taking your car to a mechanic and saying it doesn't work, and expecting him to fix it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "it doesnt work"?

Comment: The code would have worked had you been lending money, bananas, or gum but definitely not books. You should change the title to be relevant to the actual question at hand. Not only is book lending irrelevant to the question but so is C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this statement in your stored procedure

```
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM book_lending inner join studentlibrary ON studentlibrary.Book_id=book_lending.bookid where Book_id=@bookid)
```

Once a book has been checked out once, no matter if it has been returned or not, this will always have a result.  You are not deleting the record of the book being lent out (good idea).  Update this to exclude those records showing that the book has been returned

```
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM book_lending inner join 
studentlibrary ON studentlibrary.Book_id=book_lending.bookid 
Where Book_id=@bookid AND book_lending.returnstatus<>'Returned')
```

This update should essentially return the book to ready for lending again.